# trying to create a button to capture 3 inputed items and send it to another tabbed fragment page

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new and this is my first program. I am trying to create a bills program for my self. it has 3 tabs. in the second tab a user would enter bill name, bill amount, and due date. there a button to submit the entered info and it would display in tab 3.  I am trying to write the code for the button submit

```
package com.example.pking.mybudget;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class enterFragment extends Fragment  {

    EditText etBillName, etDate, etAmount;
    Button btnEnter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enter, container, false);

        etBillName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBillName);
        etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
        etAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmount);
        btnEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);

        btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String bill = etBillName.getText().toString();
                String date = etDate.getText().toString();
                String amount = etAmount.getText().toString();






            }
        });



    }


    }

take the data from tab 2 that was entered and display it in tab 3 using a for loop
```

Comment: I get a error in the findViewByID

Answer (score 0):

Apply these changes and try again.

Create a variable and assign inflated view to that.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enter, container, false);
```

if variables such as etBillName and others are inside **fragment_enter** fragment, Then initialize your variables using that view

```
etBillName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etBillName);
```

At the end of your onCreateView method, `**return rootView**`

Comment: Thanks for the info I will give it a try. I have  all the concepts in my head just sorting them out and apply it to my first program has been challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Paul.I think i know why you are getting an error while calling findViewById() method.That's because you need the View object to have an access to your widgets and also the return view line should be the very last line of your code inside your onCreateView() method.Try the following:

```html
package com.example.pking.mybudget;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class enterFragment extends Fragment  {

    EditText etBillName, etDate, etAmount;
    Button btnEnter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        
View myFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enter, container, false);

        etBillName = (EditText)myFragment.findViewById(R.id.etBillName);
        etDate = (EditText)myFragment.findViewById(R.id.etDate);
        etAmount = (EditText)myFragment.findViewById(R.id.etAmount);
        btnEnter = (Button)myFragment.findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);

        btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String bill = etBillName.getText().toString();
                String date = etDate.getText().toString();
                String amount = etAmount.getText().toString();






            }
        });
         return myFragment;

    }


    }*emphasized text*
```

You can use SharedPreferences in order to save the primitive data and then you can easily display them in your 3rd tab.I hope you find my answer useful.

Comment: look like after I added the suggested code  the findViewById is still red  and says cant resolve method

Comment: Can you tell me if the redness of findVIewById() appears only in case of this fragment or findViewByID() gets red while using in other activities or fragments. If this error occurs for all the activities and fragments then the mistake might be made else were in your other activities or fragments. Sometimes just rebuilding or cleaning your project might be helpful

Comment: this is the only page that has it,  I have ran a clean and rebuild. on the red FindViewById  the error code says : error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int). I don't know if this helps

Comment: Hi Paul, i'm little bit confused that the error still appears. Is it possible for you to show me the code of your xml layout, which you try to inflate? Maybe that's the location of the mistake.

Comment: Vakho Kurdedze please see link for the code   https://app.box.com/s/rwa7xxoy4mbg0ygv84j81unrpxrnx1bn

Comment: Hello again Paul. I saw your code and you are still missing something inside your enterFragment.  while accessing your EditTexts and Buttons, don't use just findViewById() ,but instead use rootView.findViewById(). I hope the error will disappear

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad that your problem is solved.